# Reading a _bstr_t from a file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, io

I have a problem that should be simple, but is becoming a can of worms. I have searched the Microsoft documentation and StackOverflow, but no luck.

I want to read a `_bstr_t` from a file in C++.  The file is just an Ascii text file, created in notepad.

I want it to work like `std::ifstream getline`. The standard C++ libraries eg iostream dont work with _bstr_t. I need a alternative to `getline` or `get`. I can read as a `wstring` and then convert to `_bstr_t`, but I want a simple, standard alternative.

I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio, integrating an old C API, as well as ADO for a simple database upload. I am trying to keep my application lean. I am not using MFC, there is no UI, no .NET

Thanks

Comment: How is the BSTR encoded within the file?  Is the file a binary file that actually has the BSTR serialized out (length + string + null char)?  Just a plain Ascii file?  Unicode file?

Comment: @selbie Its just a text file, ASCII

Comment: What's the problem with `getline`-ing into a `wstring` and then constructing the `BSTR` from that? It seems like a perfectly fine approach.

Comment: As ComicSansMS said, you store chars in txt file , so you can read it back using  std::ifstream getline,  use _bstr_t("charfromfile") to get you bstr.